Remove empty elements from yaml in R
I would like to remove some empty elements from a YAML in R. Empty elements could be shown as [] in a yaml. I found the ymlthis package with the  yml_discard(~is_yml_blank(.x)) option. This should remove the empty elements from the yaml but this doesn't work. Here is a reproducible example:
library(yaml)
library(ymlthis)
z <- yaml.load(
  "tree:
  format: newick
tracks:
  - class: colorstrip
    rel_height: []
    title: ")

y <- as.yaml(z)

y |>
  yml_discard(~is_yml_blank(.x))
#> ---
#> tree:
#>   format: newick
#> tracks:
#> - class: colorstrip
#>   rel_height: []
#>   title: null
#> ---

Created on 2024-11-08 with reprex v2.1.1
As you can see it doesn't remove the empty values. My expected output should look like this:
#> ---
#> tree:
#>   format: newick
#> tracks:
#> - class: colorstrip
#> ---

The expected output shows that the elements with no value should be removed. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to remove empty elements in a YAML file in R?

It seems easier to work with z, which is a tree (or in R terms an arbitrary depth nested list), than y, which is a string (or character vector of length one). For example, use rrapply::rapply() to prune any empty elements of z, then convert to a yaml string:
rrapply::rrapply(z, \(x) !is.null(x), how = "prune") |>
    as.yaml()

This returns:
tree:
  format: newick
tracks:
- class: colorstrip


With purrr we could also opt for modify_tree() + compact():
library(yaml)
library(purrr)

z <- yaml.load(
  "tree:
  format: newick
tracks:
  - class: colorstrip
    rel_height: []
    title: ")

modify_tree(z, post = compact) |> 
  as.yaml() |> 
  cat()
#> tree:
#>   format: newick
#> tracks:
#> - class: colorstrip

Created on 2024-11-08 with reprex v2.1.1

You need to iterate through every level of the list
yml_discard() only considers the top-level of your yaml. To do what you are wanting, you'll need to iterate through the depth of the list, and discard empty items as you go. We can use the purrr library for this.
Incidentally, you don't need the yaml library for this example - you can read in your text with ymlthis::as_yml() directly:
library(ymlthis)
library(purrr)

y <- ymlthis::as_yml(
"tree:
  format: newick
tracks:
  class: colorstrip
  rel_height: []
  title: ")

As noted above, yml_discard() only considers the top level of your yaml:
## Iterates over first level:
y |>
  yml_discard(~ length(.x) > 1)
#> ---
#> tree:
#>   format: newick
#> ---

Create a self-invoking function
drop_all_empty() is function that drops every zero-length item from the top level of the list, and then applies itself to every remaining list within the list. Non list items are simply returned.
## Iterative dropping of empty values

drop_all_empty <- function(x){
    
  ## Discard any empty values
    discard(x, \(z) length(z) < 1) |> 
      ## Then, for every remaining list item:
      map(
        \(a){
          ## If it's a list, 'go round again' with this function
          if(is.list(a)) drop_all_empty(a)

          ## if it's not a list, return it
          else a
        })
}

Finally, because the output of drop_all_empty() will be a list, we can create a small wrapper that converts the list back into yaml:
drop_empty_yaml <- function(x){
  drop_all_empty(x) |> 
    as_yml()
}

# presto!
drop_empty_yaml(y)
#> ---
#> tree:
#>   format:
#>   - newick
#> tracks:
#>   class:
#>   - colorstrip
#> ---

Created on 2024-11-08 with reprex v2.1.1

This is a nice answer and I love purrr but it seems harder to use it here than rrapply. As reading in y with ymlthis::as_yml() gives you an object that's list-like, it seems easier to get the desired output with rrapply::rrapply(y, \(x) !(length(x) < 1 || is.null(x)), how = "prune")
